# How can I disable add forward button at email login of cpanel?

Tags: cpanel

I have a server with cpanel, when someone login to his email acount via webmail he can add a forwarder. How can i disable that button so only me can add button?
 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are asking your question at wrong place because its third party application and its issues are handled by cPanel. So always ask to cpanel forum.

**Solution:**

Now there is no option to hide it but you can do it by CSS and Js.

Current open thread is here:

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-disabling-mail-forwarder-on-webmail.100393/